# Bot for Spacewar PPCG KotH

Tags: javascript, beginner

I wrote a bot for a [Programming Puzzles & Code Gold](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) King of the Hill type of challenge called ["Spacewar!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67560/king-of-the-hill-spacewar). The challenge was written by @El'endiaStarman. The bot is called "Spy".

The controller is hosted [here](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/spacewar/), so take a look for the feel. The API is a bit long, so [here's a link.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67560/king-of-the-hill-spacewar/)

The bot's logic:

> It runs away from the other bot with a 70% chance of firing a missile and hyperspaces when it's close to the sun.

It's not online yet at a seperate bot; so you can copy-paste the code [here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/fadcaaf5176fa3435d92066ded8395b4) into the KotH controller's text area at the bottom to test it out.

I sorta just monkey-patched this bot together without an IDE, so the code isn't that great. Seriously, there's even an extra function I didn't use.

### The code

```
function Spy_setup(team) {
  // Typical setup. Nothing to see here. ;)
  var botVars = {};
  botVars["color"] = team;
  return botVars;
}


function Spy_getActions(gameInfo, botVars) {
    var actions = [];
    var us, them, red = {
            rotation: gameInfo.red_rot,
            x: gameInfo.red_x,
            y: gameInfo.red_y,
            alive: gameInfo.blue_alive
        },
        blue = {
            rotation: gameInfo.blue_rot,
            x: gameInfo.blue_x,
            y: gameInfo.blue_y,
            alive: gameInfo.blue_alive
        };
    if (botVars.color == "red") {
        us = red;
        them = blue;
    } else if (botVars.color == "blue") {
        us = blue;
        them = red;
    }

    function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        return Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    }

    // Get our ship's position
    var rotation, x, y, opponentAlive;
    if (botVars.color == "red") {
        rotation = gameInfo.red_rot;
        x = gameInfo.red_x;
        y = gameInfo.red_y;
        opponentAlive = gameInfo.blue_alive;
    } else if (botVars.color == "blue") {
        rotation = gameInfo.blue_rot;
        x = gameInfo.blue_x;
        y = gameInfo.blue_y;
        opponentAlive = gameInfo.red_alive;
    }

    // Calculate our rotation compared to the sun in degrees
    var sunX = gameInfo.sun_x,
        sunY = gameInfo.sun_y,
        angle = Math.atan2(sunY - y, sunX - x) * 180 / Math.PI,
        rotationToSun = (rotation - angle + 360) % 360;

    // Check if we need to hyperspace to avoid the sun
    var rX = x - sunX,
        rY = y - sunY,
        distanceFromSun = Math.sqrt(rX * rX + rY * rY) - gameInfo.sun_r;
    if (distanceFromSun < 30) {
        actions.push("hyperspace");
        console.log("Command Module is Hyperspacing.")
    }
    if (gameInfo[botVars["color"] + "_alive"]) {
        var angle = Math.degrees(Math.atan2(them.y - us.y, them.x - us.x)),
            rotationToOpponent = (us.rotation - angle + 360) % 360;
        if (rotationToOpponent > 90 && rotationToOpponent < 270) {
            actions.push("turn right");
        } else {
            actions.push("turn left");
        };
        actions.push("fire engine");
        if (Math.random() > 0.3) {
            actions.push("fire missile")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

### Bugs

```
var us, them, red = {
        rotation: gameInfo.red_rot,
        x: gameInfo.red_x,
        y: gameInfo.red_y,
        alive: gameInfo.blue_alive
    },
    blue = {
        rotation: gameInfo.blue_rot,
        x: gameInfo.blue_x,
        y: gameInfo.blue_y,
        alive: gameInfo.blue_alive
    };
```

Red and blue are using the same `alive` variable.

Also...

```
if (distanceFromSun < 30) {
    actions.push("hyperspace");
    console.log("Command Module is Hyperspacing.")
}
if (gameInfo[botVars["color"] + "_alive"]) {
```

I don't think dead ships are supposed to hyperspace.

### Licensing

When you use code from StackExchange, like from [this answer to the PPCG challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67560/king-of-the-hill-spacewar/67614#67614), you should at the very least add a comment referencing the original source.

### Duplication

Without looking at the code in detail, I spot this bit of duplication:

```
var rotation, x, y, opponentAlive;
if (botVars.color == "red") {
    rotation = gameInfo.red_rot;
    x = gameInfo.red_x;
    y = gameInfo.red_y;
    opponentAlive = gameInfo.blue_alive;
} else if (botVars.color == "blue") {
    rotation = gameInfo.blue_rot;
    x = gameInfo.blue_x;
    y = gameInfo.blue_y;
    opponentAlive = gameInfo.red_alive;
}
```

```
if (gameInfo[botVars["color"] + "_alive"]) {
```

You should pick one style and stick with it. I think you could get rid of a lot of the duplication by using the second style:

```
var rotation, x, y, opponentAlive;
rotation = gameInfo[botVars.color + "_rot"];
x = gameInfo[botVars.color + "_x"];
y = gameInfo[botVars.color + "_y"];
```

Leaves us with the `opponentAlive` variable, though.

For that, I'd just go with a function `getOppositeColor`:

```
function getOppositeColor(ownColor){
    return ownColor === "blue" ? "red" : "blue";
}
```

And then we can get `opponentAlive` via

```
opponentAlive = gameInfo[getOppositeColor(botVars.color) + "_alive"];
```

---

Other weird things in your code are that you explicitly declare a `distance` function... and then you don't use it. You make objects for `red` and `blue`, but you don't use them and then extract values from `gameInfo` a second time...

You should get the variables once. Then use them. Make a single flow like that.

```
var actions = [];
var us, them, red = {
        rotation: gameInfo.red_rot,
        x: gameInfo.red_x,
        y: gameInfo.red_y,
        alive: gameInfo.red_alive
    },
    blue = {
        rotation: gameInfo.blue_rot,
        x: gameInfo.blue_x,
        y: gameInfo.blue_y,
        alive: gameInfo.blue_alive
    };
if (botVars.color == "red") {
    us = red;
    them = blue;
} else if (botVars.color == "blue") {
    us = blue;
    them = red;
}
```

This part, in that regard, is perfectly fine.

```
var rotation, x, y, opponentAlive;
if (botVars.color == "red") {
    rotation = gameInfo.red_rot;
    x = gameInfo.red_x;
    y = gameInfo.red_y;
    opponentAlive = gameInfo.blue_alive;
} else if (botVars.color == "blue") {
    rotation = gameInfo.blue_rot;
    x = gameInfo.blue_x;
    y = gameInfo.blue_y;
    opponentAlive = gameInfo.red_alive;
}
```

This entire part can go. It's not needed. You already have all of these variables as `us.rotation`, `us.x`, `us.y`, and `them.alive`.

---

```
    if (rotationToOpponent > 90 && rotationToOpponent < 270) {
        actions.push("turn right");
    } else {
        actions.push("turn left");
    };
```

Also, you don't need a semicolon to end this if-statement here.

Comment: I'm really bad at JS, thanks for the tips. Some of the code I copied from other bots. I put some of the stuff there to be compatible with other bot's code.

Comment: Also, in my answer I cited the two other bots I took code from.

Comment: You don't have a link to the answer anywhere in this question.